# graphics for android app

Tags: android, graphics

Hi I have been asked to develop an android app as part of my course. It has been agreed upon that this will be a quiz based app which will make use of graphical animations to provide questions for users to answer.

I have no experience in programming any graphics apart from a few tutorials I have looked at.    I am wondering if it is possible to create images in photoshop and then use these as objects that will be manipulated via methods or will all graphics have to be created via coding.  Any help in the situation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-ui-workshop-build-an-interactive-quiz-app/

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Android Animations**](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html).

Since it's a quiz based app, you might be interested in using [**Card Flip Animations**](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html), where on one face of the card you show the question and on the other face, have the answer.

There is also an excellent [tutorial by Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html) on Animations.